# Issues with extracting 1 column from https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/fares-and-concessions

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I tried using web scarping to extract only one column from this website[image: but could not extract succesfully]

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/fares-and-concessions')
df
from urllib.request import urlopen
# from Beautifulsoup4 import BeautifulSoup
# or if you're using BeautifulSoup4:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/fares-and-concessions').read())

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'spad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print(tds[0].string, tds[1].string)
```

I seriously need help,been trying this for hours already, its so hard just to extract 1 column :[

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is navigate through the web site try this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/fares-and-concessions').read())

# get the first table body on the accordion
table = soup("ul", id="accordion")[0].li.table.tbody

for row in table("tr"):
    # get the 7th column of each row
    print(row("td")[6].text)
```

I prefer to use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org) we use it in my [job](https://bitmaker.la), but if your are going to start on web scraping I recommend you to learn xpath it will help you to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) and selecting needed table by index from list of tables:

```
pd.read_html('https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/fares-and-concessions', header=1)[1]
```

and to get only results from the column:

```
pd.read_html('https://www.sbstransit.com.sg/fares-and-concessions', header=1)[1]['DTL/NEL']
```